# "Missing Update Command" Ubuntu/Android Dual boot App

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I'm using the android app to dual boot Ubuntu touch and android 4.4.2 stock on a nexus 10. After the app downloads the required files it goes to install them but gets the error

```
Cannot accses /cache/system/-No file or directory (2)

Missing Update Command
```

How to solve this?

---

OK so I did what u said and I still get the same error

So I tried manually adding a system folder to the cache directory and this time I got a different error that occurs after it creates the swap space. The error is 
"Missing update command" again

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the files can't be extracted to the correct directory because a lack of root access.

I managed to solve it by performing the following steps:

1. In the Ubuntu Dual-boot app deleting the downloaded files (options
   -> delete...)
2. Reboot the phone
3. Do NOT delete the /cache as the manual says.
4. Start the installation again and when prompted allow SU access.
   **PAY ATTENTION** there might be a timeout on the approval. I allowed SU access for this app "forever" in order to avoid repeated questions.

ALSO - If it fails do it again. For me the second time worked (I must have missed the first SU prompt in the first installation)

Device: Galaxy Nexus with CM 10.2